# Prove that the image of a curve $\alpha$(s) lies in a plane and find the equation of this plane.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The equation of the curve is:

$$\alpha (s)= \left(\frac{5}{13} \cos s , 1-\sin s, -\frac{12}{13} \cos s\right)
$$

I think the first step would be to find the first derivative (tangent vector) to the curve which is 
$$\alpha '(s)= \left( -5/13 \sin s , -\cos s, 12/13 \sin s\right)$$

Do I need to find the Frenet-Serret Basis for this question to find T,N,B?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, assuming that the curve is planar, computing the plane is quite easy. From the parametrization,  get 3 (non-colinear) points and then  compute the plane passing through those points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick 3 (non-colinear) points belonging to the curve (for example (0,0,0), (0,2,0) and $(\frac{-5}{13},1,\frac{12}{13})$) and obtain the equation of the plane passing through those points. The equation for that plane is $12x+5z=0$.

The ensure that the whole curve lies in that plane, we just need to verify that any point on the curve satisfies the equation of the plane, i.e.

$$
12 \left(\frac{5}{13} \cos s\right) + 5 \left(-\frac{12}{13} \cos s \right) = 0,
$$

which is true.